# web2py - python

Tags: web2py

I am using web2py technology for making web application. I want to know how to allow my code print a picture on a specific position on a card on clicking a button.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please is there any solutions??

Comment: I don't understand the question. Maybe try posting in the web2py forum with more explanation: http://groups.google.com/group/web2py

Comment: Could you give more detail about your problem? What is a card? Are you meaning when you click a button, it creates an HTML page that is printable, and that you will use the physical printout for a card?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question, you can use reportlab to generate a PDF that embeds images. Here is an example:

http://osdir.com/ml/web2py/2009-09/msg00963.html

You should really use the web2py mailing list for this kind of questions.

Comment: I think we should not try to close web2py in it's mailing list ghetto. There are many questions abour RoR, django and other similar frameworks. The more info about web2py the better. On the other way web2py mailing list is very good and Massimo and others are very helpful so using web2py mailing list you can get answer quickier.

Comment: Please do not discard the use of stack overflow for questions about web2py. I agree that its a way to get web2py to be more popular